# Stop Sound with other button

Tags: iphone, audio, xcode4.2, ibaction, libjingle

i try to create a small JingeMachine, to play sound mp3 wav and other i use this Action on button is TouchDown:

```
- (IBAction)NormalApplause:(id)sender {
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soudFileURLRef;
soudFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"normalApplause" , CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
UInt32 sounudID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soudFileURLRef, &sounudID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sounudID);
```

}

How can stop all sound with other Button? i will can start all sound to a multiple touch, but if is possible i will stop all in a single touch.

Can Helpme please?

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop sound played with `AudioServices`, you will need to use the [`AVAudioPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

Also if you call `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` you will need to [`AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007916-CH3-SW4) to correctly dispose of the sound ref.

Comment: Thx i see this on the net, buy i don't now how can use in a other button